# React Native File-Conversion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, multer, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert an audio file into a Base64String to upload to a server.
For certain reasons, I want to do this on the phone before I upload this. I'm using React Native inside the Expo kit.

My file structure looks like this:

```
let uriParts = uri.split('.');
let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', {
  uri,
  name: `file.${fileType}`,
  type: `audio/${fileType}`,
});
```

**Assume we have the uri and it's a .wav audio file**

I was able to do this conversion with a NodeJS server with multer doing the heavy lifting.

It would give a buffer to the route and then I could convert the buffer to a base64 string and then send it to another server to process the buffer.

Any idea how can get this done on React Native or purely on the frontend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FileReader** class.

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
```

Or you can send as a **blob** (It is not base64).
Use https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob library

Comment: FileReader is failing to read the file. Just confirming is this the file put into the formData?